# Getting huge range of values when using Flow Accumulation tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, watershed, flow-accumulation

I'm trying to use ArcGIS Desktop to delineate watersheds for a series of sampling sites. I've been following the protocol laid out by WhiteboxDev in [General steps to create watershed boundary in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116929/general-steps-to-create-watershed-boundary-in-arcgis-spatial-analyst)

However, I'm having troubles with the flow accumulation tool. When I run it based on my flow direction raster, I end up with values that range from zero to nine million, which seems wrong, and can't be used for the next steps.

[image: Screenshot of flow accumulation tool result.]

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening, and what I can do to fix it?

I haven't used any other layers to weight the output, and I think my flow direction layer is accurate.

[image: Screenshot of flow direction layer.]

I'm using the NASA SRTM elevation data, which has 1 arc-second (~30 m) cells. In Arc, the cell dimensions are listed as (0.00027777778, 0.00027777778), which I assume is in degrees. I understand the idea of the flow accumulation tool, I just don't understand why it's skewing all of my data.

Comment: The flow accumulation values are the total count of uphill cells that flow into that cell.  What are the dimensions of your input raster- the x and y counts?  If you are working with a high-resolution LiDAR dataset, say with 3ft pixels, that 9 million count watershed only needs to be 9000ft by 9000ft.

Comment: Have you tried projecting your data to a projected coordinate system?